# In Julia how to deal neatly with Zero Dimensions and Iterators

Tags: iterator, julia, splat

Consider the following scenario:

```
do_something( v :: Vector{ T } ) where { T <: Integer } = println( "v = $v" )

function d_dep( d :: Integer )

    axis_iters = fill( -1:1, d )

    for ig in Iterators.product( axis_iters ... )
        g = [ ig ... ]
        do_something( g )
    end
    
end
```

This is a model of what I am doing in another code, and does what I want if I provide a positive integer argument to `d_dep`:

```
julia> include( "nd.jl" )
d_dep (generic function with 1 method)

julia> d_dep( 1 )
v = [-1]
v = [0]
v = [1]

julia> d_dep( 2 )
v = [-1, -1]
v = [0, -1]
v = [1, -1]
v = [-1, 0]
v = [0, 0]
v = [1, 0]
v = [-1, 1]
v = [0, 1]
v = [1, 1]

julia>
```

Unfortunately d=0 means something in this case, and that's where things go pear-shaped:

```
julia> d_dep(0)
ERROR: MethodError: no method matching do_something(::Vector{Any})

Closest candidates are:
  do_something(::Vector{T}) where T<:Integer
   @ Main ~/julia/test/nd.jl:1

Stacktrace:
 [1] d_dep(d::Int64)
   @ Main ~/julia/test/nd.jl:9
 [2] top-level scope
   @ REPL[4]:1

julia>
```

The problem as I understand it is that when you apply the splat operator to the array `axis_iters` it gets expanded to a empty list from which `Iterators.Product` has nothing to get a type from, hence `Vector{Any}`. So two questions:

1. Currently I have a `if d == 0` in `d_dep`. This is ugly. Is there a neater way to deal with the zero d case, or the whole structure in general? If it helps d should be positive semi-definite.
2. Actually I don't really understand why when `d=0` the loop is executed at all. Why is it - is Julia like Fortran66 was alleged to be (but wasn't) in that it was mandated that all loops have at least 1 trip? [ In F66 zero trip loops were actually implementation defined ]

Comment: what would you want `do_something` to be called with if `d==0`?

Comment: In the case of d=0 in the real code do something reduces to do nothing. And this is what got me thinking why the loop is executed at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The result of `Iterators.product()` is a zero-dimensional iterator. In Julia a zero-dimensional iterators (things like `Array{Int, 0}`) are implemented to behave like a scalar**

And you can see that you can iterate over a scalar:

```
julia> for i in 1
           @show i
       end
i = 1
```

So it should not be that surprising that you can iterate over a zero-dimensional `Array`.

This is basically a language design decision, made (AFAIK) to make some broadcasting cases like `[0, 1, 2] .+ 1` work consistently. You can read more [here](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/faq/#faq-array-0dim).

As for making the code work, I see two options:

**Always make `typeof(g) == Vector{Int}`**, for example:

```
function d_dep(d::Integer)
    axis_iters = fill(-1:1, d)

    for ig in Iterators.product(axis_iters...)
        g = Int[ig...]
        do_something(g)
    end
end
```

**Or add another `do_something` method to catch the `d==0` case:**

```
julia> do_something(v::Vector) = println("v = $v")

julia> d_dep(0)
v = Any[]
```

Comment: Thanks. Both useful answers but this one reminded me that in Julia that zero rank objects at as a scalar, which is the underlying concept I was ,issuing. And why it is different from Fortran.

Answer (score 1):

The fix is to do `g = Int[ ig ... ]` as with `d=0` you currently have `[]` which has eltype `Any`, and `Int[]` will have eltype `Int`.

Regarding the second question it is the way how `Iterators.product` is implemented. See:

```
julia> collect(Iterators.product())
0-dimensional Array{Tuple{}, 0}:
()
```

So for zero arguments passed the `Iterators.product` produces one empty tuple and that is why you get the result you observe (I assume you thought it would not produce anything).

Comment: I'm from fortran land. In the equivalent case the loop would not get executed. Can you point me to where in the language spec it details this?

Comment: It is specified here https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/faq/#faq-array-0dim. It is stated there that 0-dimensional arrays have length 1 always. The person implementing `Iterators.product` made sure that when this function returns 0-dimensional result then the length of this result is 1 (producing a single empty tuple).